# Draw line through, instead of between two points in Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, line, draw, opencv3.0

I want to draw a line trough two given points in an image using OpenCV in Python. The definition of a line states as "The shortest distance between two points." But I don't want the line to stop at the points, I want it to go all the way to the borders of my image. Currently I am obviously just using the cv2.line function, with 1 being the thickness of the line.

```html
cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),blue,1)
```

The algorithm I'm writing doesn't really matter, I just can't find any function in cv2 or numpy that draws a "line" through two points instead of between them.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: solved it myself

```html
a = (1.0*(y2-y1))/(1.0*(x2-x1))
b = -a*x1+y1
y1_ = (int)(0)
y2_ = (int)(np.shape(img)[1])
x1_ = (int)((y1_-b)/a)
x2_ = (int)((y2_-b)/a)
cv2.line(img,(x1_,y1_),(x2_,y2_),(colors[i][0],colors[i][1],colors[i][2]),5)
```

Comment: You have the two points, get the line equation, get two other points on the line but outside of the image, draw the line between these two new points

Comment: This is indeed a solution to the problem. Thanks